# Access HTML of IFrame using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsf, iframe

I am trying to access a button that is being displayed in an IFrame. I then want to attach a listener for that button. However, I cant seem to be able to access the IFrame. Assume the button's id is `button`. How could I go about doing this.

Here is the code I have for an example:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
    <h:head>
        <title>Facelet Title</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <script>
            function test() {
                var temp = $("myIframe").contents();
                alert(temp);
                var temp2 = temp.find("body");
                alert(temp2);
                var temp3 = temp2.html();
                alert(temp3);
            }
        </script>
        <h:form>
            <p:commandButton value="Click" onclick="test();"/>
        </h:form>
        <iframe id="myIframe" src="http://test.com" height="200" width="500"/>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

Alerts for temp and temp2 work, but temp3 is undefined. Can someone help out?

Comment: Is the page in the IFRAME on a different site?

Comment: Yes, it is. It could be any site for that matter. I want to be able to add a listener to a button as needed.

Comment: You can not access an IFRAME of another domain

Comment: Is there a way to accomplish what I want without an IFrame? Maybe using the <embed> tag?

Comment: You could retrieve the html with jQuery and then insert it into your dom. (Embed has the same cross-domain restrictions as iframe)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No can do, for security reasons.

Imagine being able to create a page that opens up Facebook in a hidden IFRAME, then uses script to either steal auth cookies or manipulate the DOM to post spam on everyone's wall.

You cannot access content on other web sites for a *very* good reason.  You'll have to implement another way to access this other information, such as a server-side API.

Answer (score 1):

You cant access the iframe content through javascript

That could be serious security issue.

The only way you can achieve is using the CURL with PHP/some other language and render it through your server.

sample of ajax(jquery) and php CURL

```
<script>
var lat = $.ajax({
url: "function.php?function=curl",
async: false
}).responseText;
</script>
```

And then inside function.php you do your CURL, echo what you want, and you'll have the response in your lat JS Var. So if you do this:

```
<script> alert (lat); </script>
```

You should see the data from the CURL.

In function.php you'll need your curl to look like this:

```
if($_GET["function"] == "curl") {
$url = 'http://whichever.url.you.need';
 $curl_handle = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
  curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 2);
  curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
  curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie_file_path);
  curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie_file_path);
  //curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
  //curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
  $buffer = curl_exec($curl_handle);
  curl_close($curl_handle);
  // check for success or failure
  if (empty($buffer)) {
  echo 'Something went wrong :(';
  } else {
  echo $buffer;
  }
    }
```

Comment: This is very interesting. Im going to check this out

Comment: I know there is library for this. let me find for you

Answer (score 0):

If you have control over both the parent frame and the iframe, this can be done with child to parent frame messaging.

Have the parent frame listen for a message.

```
<div id="myDiv">
    <iframe src="childFrame.html" id="frame1"></iframe>
</div>

<script>    
window.onmessage = function(e) {
     if(e.data == "click") {
        alert("Button Clicked!");
     }
}
</script>
```

The iframe can send a message to the parent frame.

```
<button onclick="parent.postMessage('click', '*');">Hide</button>
```